# How to define date in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

It looks like GORM doesn't have support for DATE type, the only way to define date is through 
time.Time :

```
type Header struct {

    Start    time.Time  `json:"period_start"`
    End      time.Time  `json:"period_end" `
    CreatedAt      time.Time `json:"created_at" sql:"DEFAULT:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"`
    CreatedBy      string     `json:"created_by"`
    UpdatedAt      time.Time `json:"updated_at" sql:"DEFAULT:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"`
    UpdatedBy      string     `json:"updated_by"`
}
```

So created table will have TIMESTAMP as a type. Is there a way around this? I tried sql:"DATE", it didn't work

Answer (score 11):

Use `time.Time` type for define `Date` in Gorm

```
type Header struct {
    StartDate    time.Time  `json:"start_date"`
    ...
}
```

DB Table

```
CREATE TABLE `header` (
  ...
  `start_date` DATE DEFAULT NULL
)
```

For parsing date string use this

```
format := "2006-01-02"
date, _ := time.Parse(format, "2019-07-10")
```

In order to handle `time.Time` correctly, you need to include `parseTime` as a parameter in connection.

```
db, err = Open("mysql", "gorm:gorm@/gorm?charset=utf8&parseTime=True")
```

**Update:**

Now we can use [GORM Customized Data Types Collection](https://github.com/go-gorm/datatypes#date) for Date

Comment: hello @Eklavya. I am new here and was exploring this ORM. In you second code block, are you trying to say that i have to do it manually?

Comment: @NoobCoder Yes, you need to parse it manually. Now you can use custom date type of gorm https://github.com/go-gorm/datatypes#date